# ASP CORE: @Html.ValidationMessage migration to asp-validation-for or similar tag helper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

How to setup the `asp-validation-for` with string value, not with expression?

I want to migrate the multiselect list:

```
@Html.ListBox("Privileges", ViewBag.PrivilegesMultiSelectList as MultiSelectList)
@Html.ValidationMessage("Privileges", "")
```

to

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="Privileges" asp-items="@ViewBag.PrivilegesMultiSelectList"></select>
<span asp-validation-for="Privileges" class="text-danger"></span>
```

But the last line is invalid:

> Error CS1061  '...Model' does not contain a definition for 'Privileges'
>   and no accessible extension method 'Privileges' accepting a first
>   argument of type '..Model' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

I want to stay using tag-helper because of consistency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `asp-validation-for="Privileges"` is trying to look for `Privileges` property in your model (not ViewBag). If it doesn't exist, it will give you that error. That line is the equivalent of `ValidationMessageFor()`, and afaik there's no equivalent in .net core for `ValidationMessage()`.

Have a look at the asp-validation-for [tag helper](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/4e44025a52e4b73aa17e09a8041b0e166e0c5ce0/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/ValidationMessageTagHelper.cs#L61), which as stated should align with the name of another taghelper.

> How to setup the `asp-validation-for` with string value, not with expression?

Again, there's no equivalent for `ValidationMessage()` it in TagHelpers. So you can just use `@Html.ValidationMessage()`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2

> it's important to recognize that Tag Helpers don't replace HTML Helpers and there's not a Tag Helper for each HTML Helper.

You could also just write your own tag helper with the [ValidationMessage HtmlHelper](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/Rendering/HtmlHelperValidationExtensions.cs#L58)

Some advice from the docs regarding ViewBags:

> We don't recommend using ViewBag or ViewData with the Select Tag Helper. A view model is more robust at providing MVC metadata and generally less problematic.

**A better approach:**

You will need to add the selected Privilege(s) to your model that you wish to return.

```
public class CustomViewModel {
    [Required]
    public string Privilege { get; set; } // update if you want to return multiple privileges

    public List<SelectListItem> PrivilegesMultiSelectList { get; set; }
}
```

and then use that in your View `@model CustomViewModel`.

Using `asp-for="Privilege"` on your select, it becomes `m => m.Privilege`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.2

> The asp-for attribute value is a special case and **doesn't require a
>   Model prefix**, the other Tag Helper attributes do (such as asp-items)

You can then just write it as such:

```
<select asp-for="Privilege" asp-items="@Model.PrivilegesMultiSelectList"></select> 
<span asp-validation-for="Privilege" class="text-danger"></span>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to migrate to properties of course, as always "a little bit later".